# Can Timestamp be given as Input and display it as output in an Android application

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

In my android application, can user be able to enter the timestamp manually and submit to the database and can the same timestamp be displayed as out put.I also need to display a blob time same way.Is it possible?

In this process
just like for retrieving a text,integer we use

```
object.getText()toString();

Integer.parseInt(object.getText()toString());
```

Is there anyway like that for TimeStamp and Blob ?

please do help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the scenario little bit more?

Comment: I want user to enter an input in a field in a timestamp format yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss and be able to display as same format in the output. So how do i need to parse the input

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use ContentProvider in order to save things to database. Take a look at this tutorial.

[Android SQLite database and content provider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

To let user enter the date manually, I'll recommend you to use DatePicker.

Comment: its not just the date ..there has to be time too.. i created a database table which has a column of datatype "Datetime". I should be able to insert the values(timestamp values) given by user successfully

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. This link will help you. It has all the key details of Time and Date picker.

Comment: A content provider is not needed.

Comment: @CL. but i hope you know its a recommended way of dealing with database in Android. Yes you can execute direct sql queries on database but that is not a best practice.

Comment: I know the opposite is true. The [official DB guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) does not even mention content providers; and [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are designed to allow *interprocess* DB accesses.